# by preposition to describe location close to a person

Tags: prepositions

I know that I can use `by` to refer to a place relative to a inanimate object:

> Let's meet **by the door / building / flat**...

But what about a person? The following does not sound right:

> Let's meet **by the concierge**

What is the best way to convey the meaning?

Comment: A bit weird to meet by a person, as it is hard to know where the person is at the time, and the "concierge" in this case may not always be in the same place. Better to stick with inanimate objects

Comment: Yep, I understand the problem of meeting "nearby someone" (who can move). We can assume that concierge is always at the same place... Or maybe I should refer the place where they are supposed to be?.. The questions is relevant :)

Comment: It's a lot easier when one meets a place, rarely do people meet by someone, so its better to describe to meet at the place where the concierge is

Comment: What would you say if you had to convey the meaning: "meet by the place where concierge is supposed to be sitting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *do* use 'by' in relation to a person, however it can also be figurative. For example:

> My wife stood by me throughout my trials (figuratively means they were supported by them)

It's just a bit weird to say you would meet someone 'by' another person. A person is not a fixed place. You'd have to say where that person was in order to meet by them, surely?

However, in your example of "the concierge", I'm imagining that there might be a fixed place such as a desk in a hotel where the concierge might always be. Also, 'the concierge' in a hotel might not always be the same person, but various people on shift, so it could be acceptable. I still think it would be more likely we would say "meet by the concierge's desk". I would think it weird if someone said "let's meet by the receptionist" rather than 'the reception', as there are two clear terms for the area and the person.

Comment: Yep. I understand the problem. What would you say if you had to convey the meaning: "let's meet by the place where concierge is supposed to be sitting"?

Comment: @DimanNe I've just updated my answer, and yes I think that would probably sound ok.

Answer (score 1):

It is rare to meet *by* a person, always better to meet by an inanimate object. So if you wanted to meet somewhere where the concierge is, one might say the below if you view the concierge as "a resident caretaker"

> Let's meet by the front of this hotel

or if you view the concierge as "a hotel employee"

> Let's meet by the front of this [restaurant/theater]

> Let's meet by the [front counter/receptionist counter] of this hotel

Concierge meanings

> 1. (especially in France) a resident caretaker of a block of flats or a small hotel.

> 2. a hotel employee whose job is to assist guests by booking tours, making theatre and restaurant reservations, etc.

Source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concierge)